# A normal, idempotent linear operator must be self-adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been trying to solve this problem for quite a while. I am still unsure of whether any of the avenues I have pursued have been of any use. Any advice will be much appreciated.

**Question:**

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional inner product space, and let $E$ be an idempotent linear operator on $V$. Prove that if $EE^* = E^*E$, then $E$ is self-adjoint.

(This is essentially exercise 5(a) in sec. 80 on p.162 of Paul R. Halmos, *Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces*, but Halmos didn't assume that the dimension of $V$ is finite.)

Comment: Well, if you want to use a big hammer, the spectral theorem says that normal operators are unitarily diagonalizable.  So it suffices to consider the case where $E$ is diagonal, which should be pretty easy.

Comment: Is this true also for infinite dimensional spaces?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If $E$ is normal, $\| E x \| = \|E^* x \|$ for all $x$.  Similarly, $I-E$ is normal,
so $\|(I-E) x\| = \|(I - E^*)x \|$.  In particular, since $(I-E)Ex = 0$, $(I-E^*)Ex = 0$, i.e. $E^* E = E$, and similarly since $E(I-E)x = 0$,  $E^*(I-E)x = 0$, i.e. $E^* E  = E^* $.  But those together say  $E = E^*$.

Comment: How do you get  $ (I−E)Ex=0$  implies $(I−E^∗)Ex=0 $ ?

Comment: @Napster: Zero is the unique element with zero norm, so if you know that one is zero, then by preservation of the norm, the other has to be zero as well

Answer (score 13):

**Update.** As $E$ is normal and idempotent, direct calculation shows that
$$
(E-E^\ast E)^\ast(E-E^\ast E)=0=(E^\ast-E^\ast E)^\ast(E^\ast-E^\ast E).\tag{1}
$$
Note that for any linear operator $A$, if $A^\ast A=0$, then $\langle Ax,Ax\rangle=\langle x,A^\ast Ax\rangle=0$ for every vector $x$, so that $A=0$. It follows from $(1)$ that $E-E^\ast E=0=E^\ast-E^\ast E$. Hence $E=E^\ast E=E^\ast$.

---

**(Old answer:)**

The equality $EE^\ast=E^\ast E$ implies that $(E+E^\ast-I)(E-E^\ast)=0$. If you can show that $E+E^\ast-I$ is invertible, you are done.

Suppose $(E+E^\ast -I)v=0$. Left-mulitply the equation by $E^\ast$, we get $E^\ast Ev=0$. Hence show that $Ev=0$. Since $EE^\ast=E^\ast E$, similarly, show that $E^\ast v=0$. Now, consider the equation $(E+E^\ast -I)v=0$ again and show that $E+E^\ast -I$ is invertible.

Comment: How do you get $Ev=0$? I don't see that...

Comment: @5space $E^\ast Ev=0\Rightarrow v^\ast E^\ast Ev=0$.