# Prove that idempotent operator $E$ is self-adjoint if and only if $EE^∗$ = $E^∗E$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional inner product space, and let $E$ be an idempotent
linear operator on $V$, i.e., $E^2 = E$. Prove that E is self-adjoint if and only if $EE^* = E^*E$.

Are there any simpler answers to the question that the answers provided here [Normal, idempotent operator implies self-adjointness.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319197/normal-idempotent-operator-implies-self-adjointness/) . Both answers seem to be correct but contain logical steps that I can't comprehend e.g $(I−E)Ex=0 \Rightarrow (I−E^∗)Ex=0 $ and $v^\ast E^\ast Ev=0 \Rightarrow Ev=0$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $E^2=E$. Then $E$ has a basis of eigenvectors with eigenvalues $0$ and $1$ because every vector can be written as
$$
                x = Ex + (I-E)x,
$$
and $\;$ $Ex$, $(I-E)x$ $\;$ satisfies
\begin{align}
               E(Ex)&=1\cdot Ex,\\
               E(I-E)x &= 0 \cdot (I-E)x.
\end{align}
$E$ is selfadjoint iff these eigenspaces are mutually orthogonal, which is equivalent to the condition that
$$
            \langle Ex,(I-E)y\rangle=0,\;\;\; \forall x,y, \\
      \iff \langle x,E^*(I-E)y\rangle = 0, \;\;\; \forall x,y, \\
      \iff E^*(I-E)y=0,\;\; \forall y \\
      \iff E^*(I-E) = 0 \\
      \iff E^* = E^*E
$$
The last condition holds iff $E^*=E^*E = (E^*E)^*=E$.

Comment: I like much your nickname.

Comment: I'm still a little confused - how does this prove $E^*=E$ from $EE^* = E^*E$?  Does $E^*E = EE^*$ imply $<Ex, (I-E)y> = 0$ somehow?

Comment: @Willcarbog : I was using $E^*=E^*E$ to show that $E=(E^*)^*=(E^*E)^*=E^*E=E^*$.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how $E^*E = EE^* \implies E = E^*$. I understand how $E^* = E^*E \implies E = E^*$ from your answer above, but am confused on how $E^*E=EE^* \implies E^* = E^*E$ (or if you managed $E^*E = EE^* \implies E = E^*$ in some other way)

Comment: @Willcarbog : $E^*E$ is always selfadjoint. So, if $E^*=E^*E$, then $E^*$ is selfadjoint, which is equivalent to $E$ being selfadjoint. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $E$ is self-adjoint then $E=E^*$, So $EE^*=E^2=E^*E$. Now suppose conversely that $EE^*=E^*E$ then, $<EE^*(v),E^*E(v)> = <EE^*(v),E(v)>$ and also $$<E^*E(v),EE^*(v)> = <E(v),EE^*(v)> = <E^*E(v), E^*(v)>$$ and hence from these two equations that are true for all $v$ in $V$. We get $E^*(v)=E(v)$ for all $v$ belong to $V$ that is, $E$ is self adjoint.